# How much force would the wind of Saturn (1800 Km/hour) exert on my body if i appear on its surface?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, pressure, atmospheric-science, planets

Maybe I should have said pressure. I don't know how to measure the exact pressure of the air molecules on my skin, anyways was curious to know this, like what exactly will happen to my body if i suddenly magically appear on Saturn's surface ? Will I be squeezed to death or maybe just get hit from a few air molecules like a hammer would hit and just die from that?

Comment: The answer depends on the density of the atmosphere which in turn depends on how deep you are in Saturn's atmosphere.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: check the answers to this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/522756/running-on-the-outside-of-a-moving-train

Comment: @gandalf61 i meant to be on the surface of saturn, which is like the deepest point ?
edited the question

Comment: @jim thanks for this but i don't understand how it relates exactly.